# How to nest strings and group in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After 3 collections was joined and many many groupings later i have documents like:

```
{
"Request" : "first",
"TotalRequests" : 12,
"Organization" : "A",
"TotalRequestsByOrganization" : 3,
"user" : "John Smith",
"TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 1
},

{
"Request" : "first",
"TotalRequests" : 12,
"Organization" : "A",
"TotalRequestsByOrganization" : 3,
"user" : "John Galt",
"TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 2
},

{
"Request" : "first",
"TotalRequests" : 12,
"Organization" : "B",
"TotalRequestsByOrganization" : 7,
"user" : "Chris Evans",
"TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 4
},

{
"Request" : "first",
"TotalRequests" : 12,
"Organization" : "B",
"TotalRequestsByOrganization" : 7,
"user" : "Charlie",
"TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 3
},

{
"Request" : "second",
"TotalRequests" : 3,
"Organization" : "B",
"TotalRequestsByOrganization" : 3,
"user" : "James Anthony",
"TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 3
}
```

etc.

How to group my documents, when "user" and "TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" is nested into "Organization" and "TotalRequestsByOrganization", and they are part of "Request" and "TotalRequests"?

What i want in result:

```
{
"Request" : {
"name" : "first",
"TotalRequests" : 12,
"Organization": {
          "Orgname": "A",
          "TotalRequestsByOrganization": 3,
          "users": {
                    "user" : "John Smith",
                    "TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 1,
                    "user" : "John Galt",
                    "TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization" : 2
}}}}
```

Comment: You mean that there is 3 level of groupings: 1. Request and TotalRequests 2. Organization and TotalRequestsByOrganization 3. user and TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization ? and you want to group each lower level's record into an array of higher level? Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y_BRoo-ZjgS) ?

Comment: Yes! Many thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the expected result by 2 `$group`:

1. `$group` by finest level: `Request, TotalRequests, Organization, TotalRequestsByOrganization`; use `$push` to put all `user` and `TotalRequestsByUserInOrganization` tuple into an array `user`
2. `$group` by coarser level: `Request, TotalRequests`; use `$push` to put all `Orgname`, `TotalRequestsByOrganization` and `users` array into an array `Organization`
3. At the most coarse level, `$project` the field to wrangle the output to your expected format

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y_BRoo-ZjgS) for your reference.